# Running multiple program from bash script within for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run multiple instances of a node server using a bash script. I parametrized node such that I could change the port at each cycle, but it seems I cannot run it properly. This is what I wrote (and doesn't start anything). It looks pretty ugly, I'm very new to bash scripting.

```
#!/bin/bash

#iterate input times and start server
COUNT=$1
TIMEOUT=$2
PORT=3000

while [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]; do
        A="node server.js "
        B=PORT
        C=" "
        D=TIMEOUT
        CMD=$A$B$C$D
        $CMD
        let PORT=PORT+10
        let COUNT=COUNT-1
done
```

`TIMEOUT` is just another variable that I pass to the server instance.

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot, and sorry if the script looks ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TIMEOUT=$2
for((count=$1,port=3000;count>0;--count,port+=10)); do
    node server.js $port $TIMEOUT &
done
```

You have way too many lost `$`-signs.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! That worked fine and looks way much cleaner than my ugly script. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to start a new thread, because otherwise the execution will wait for the process started with your command to exit. To do that, simply append ' & ' to the command, i.e.

```
...
$CMD &
...
```